# Trying to root Motorola Xoom. Stuck rebooting

Tags: rooting, motorola-xoom

I am rooting my Motorola Xoom wifi tablet following these instructions:

http://www.droid-life.com/2011/02/25/how-to-root-the-motorola-xoom/

I unlocked the bootloader fine. And I got to this point:

1. Type:  adb reboot bootloader
2. Type:  fastboot flash boot rootboot.img
3. Type:  fastboot reboot
4. Wait for your device to reboot all the way.

Except it never rebooted all the way. It is stuck on a black screen with a red M motorola logo and the words Dual Core Technology. Its been about 20 minutes or so now. Should it be taking this long? and if not how can a make it to try rebooting again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that you need a different boot.img file for the Motorola Xoom wifi only model than for the 3g model.

[Click here for instructions if you have a 3g model](http://www.droid-life.com/2011/02/25/how-to-root-the-motorola-xoom/)

[click here for instructions if you have the wifi only model](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1010568) (Including how to fix it if you've already tried using the wrong boot.img and you are being stared at by a non-responsive boot screen that has the Moto logo and the words 'Dual Core Technology')

Comment: your second link there is broken?

Comment: Dunno what happened. Its fixed now though.